# summing values that match text critera

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a need to create an Excel Sheet that can compare a column of employees' names to a second sheet that has a certain number of monetary figures, as such:

list of specific employees who's profit I need to figure on Sheet 1

> Bob Smith
>
> John Doe
>
> Jane Gold

list of all employees with various profit amounts on Sheet 2

```
Alan Parsons  300

Alan Parsons  245

Alan Parsons  245

Bob Smith     300

Bob Smith     300

John Doe      200

John Doe      200

John Doe      150

John Doe      135

Jane Gold     300

Jane Gold     200

Mark Sanchez  300

Mark Sanchez  250
```

So what I need is a formula that can sum just the values next to the names on Sheet 2 that match the master list on Sheet 1, and I have been unable to discover how SUMIF or SUMIFS can accomplish this, so the end result, on Sheet 1 would be:

```
Bob Smith   600

John Doe    685

Jane Gold   500
```

Answer (score 2):

in sheet 1 cell b2 `=SUMIF('Sheet 2'!A:A,A2,'Sheet 2'!B:B)`

Comment: Thank you!  I see my error was in the criteria section of the formula: i kept trying to put a multiple cell range in instead of just the one reference cell!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [sumif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)

If bob, john and jane are in A1, A2, and A3 on sheet1, in B1 put:

`=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,A1,Sheet2!$B:$B)`

To look up the table in columns A and B on sheet2. Now you can just drag B1 down to B2 and B3 to get the totals.

Comment: Thank you!  I see my error was in the criteria section of the formula: i kept trying to put a multiple cell range in instead of just the one reference cell!  Much appreciated!